# Invalid or unexpected token when trying passing json as parameter to inline function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to pass an object (`data[i]`) from `for` loop to a function in `onclick` property, but getting the error

> Invalid or unexpected token

from this:

```
 textmydata += '<td style="text-align:center"><a onclick="Edit(\'' +
 JSON.stringify(data[i]) + '\');" class="btn btn-info" title="Edit"><i 
class="icon-pencil"> Edit</i></a> <a onclick="Remove(' + data[i].ColorCode +
 ')" class="btn btn-danger" title="Remove"><i class="icon-cancel-3"> Remove</i></a>
</td></tr>';
```

tried a lot to concatenate quotes to the json object, but always the same error, also tried without `JSON.stringify`, the object passed successfully to the `Edit` function but as `[object object]`

This is the output HTML

```
    <td style="text-align:center"><a onclick="Edit('{" 
studentcode":2,"studentname":"الاسم","birthdate":"2014-03-30t00:00:00","educationstagecode":1,"areacode":0,"studentfathername":"الأب",
"studentmothername":"الأم","isfatheralife":true,"studentfatherjob":"وظيفة="" الأب","fathertel":"01000","ismotheralife":true,"studentmotherjob":"ست="" بيت",
"mothertel":"02222","address":"مصر","tel":"011","isactive":true,
"isdeleted":false}');"="" class="btn btn-info" title="تعديل">
<i class="icon-pencil"> تعديل</i></a> <a onclick="Remove(2)" class="btn btn-danger" title="حذف"><i class="icon-cancel-3"> حذف</i></a></td>
```

Comment: Don't use inline javascript, especially not like that

Comment: working on legacy code, and don't have the choice!

Comment: What is the value of `data[i].ColorCode`?

Comment: Why don't you have the choice? Can't you use the standard way of `appendChild` and such?

Comment: It will help to identify the problem if you posted the *resulting* HTML string and not just the way the HTML string is being created

Comment: @CertainPerformance Prvided the output, please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that JSON uses double quote as its string delimiter, and the first of these quotes will match the double quote in `onclick="`.

You can replace all the double quotes in the JSON with their corresponding HTML entity, `&quot;`.

```
textmydata += '<td style="text-align:center"><a onclick="Edit(\'' +
    JSON.stringify(data[i]).replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + 
    '\');" class="btn btn-info" title="Edit"><i class="icon-pencil"> Edit</i></a> <a onclick="Remove(' + 
    data[i].ColorCode +
    ')" class="btn btn-danger" title="Remove"><i class="icon-cancel-3"> Remove</i</a></td></tr>';
```

Comment: I'm confused about the single and double quotes of JavaScript, could you please review the code, there's "unterminated string constant" error

Comment: Please answer my query or delete the answer because I need to delete this question !

Comment: Sorry, had an extra quote before the regexp in `.replace()`.